# Can New Relic Java agent miss sending last one minute metrics data in case of JVM crash?

Tags: java, newrelic, instrumentation, apm

New Relic has a Java agent which can be added as a dependency to the application. The agent does instrumentation as part of the running JVM I believe. And that instrumented data is sent to New Relic server every one minute from the Java agent.

In case JVM crashes/exits (for any reason) before agent gets a chance to send last minute interval data, will the metrics be lost? Or does data get persisted in disk from where agent can read & send it when the JVM is up again? But that might be delayed & not real time. So we will miss vital data that can help in debugging the crash.

May be I am missing something. If anyone has more insight about how New Relic Java agent handles this scenario, please answer.